# Intersect arrays with different key

Tags: php, arrays

How do intersect two arrays array1 and array2.

$array1 contains data from database table, key of array1 values has to start from 4 and increments by 2. The structure of the table is (id, name, purpose, t1, p1, t2, p2, t3, p3...)

key and value for $array1

```
$array1 = array(
    [0] => 1, [1] => English, [2] => comm, [3] => Que1, [4] => A, [5] => Que2
)
```

$array2 contains values received from submitted form. key of array2 values starts from 1 and increments by 1.

key and value for $array2

```
$array2 = array(
    [1] => A, [2] => C, [3] => B, [4] => E, [5] => C
)
```

The code

```
//values from submitted form
foreach($_POST as $answer) {
    $array2 = $_POST['question'];
    $qcount = sizeof($array2);
}
$j = 4;
$tCorr = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i < $qcount + 1; $i++) {
    $correct_array = array_intersect_assoc($array1[$j], $array2[$i]);
    $tCorr = sizeof($correct_array);
    $tCorr++;
    $j = $j + 2;
}
```

How do i make $array1 start from key 4 ($j) and array2 start from key 1 ($i).
Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Please add the arrays and show how you want them to intersect.

Comment: hello Sarcoma, i just added the array

Comment: Thanks, in your `foreach` loop you are not using `$answer` what is this loop meant to achieve?

Comment: Just to be sure I understood your question... What values do you expect to be in the `$correct_array`?

Comment: @Sarcoma: i looked at an example to implement that part. not sure what the $answer should do. will appreciate recommendation

Comment: OK, a `foreach` loop will iterate of each element in an array (in this case `$_POST` is the array) and assign the nth element to the `as` variable (in this case `$answer`) to be used or some how manipulated in the loop. In this example `$answer` isn't being used inside the loop, which is a bit odd.

Comment: @Washington Guedes The $correct_array is supposed to contain the values in array1 that correspond to values in array2 using the key

Comment: This isn't necessarily part of you problem, but you should try to understand what your code is doing as you will end up with bugs later.

Comment: I'd suggest doing a bit more research on the `for`, `foreach` and `while` loops, and come back to your problem once you understand them a little better. You'll likely find it makes more sense.

Comment: Also check the documentation for `array_intersect_assoc` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php. It doesn't look like it needs to be in a loop, if the arrays are comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi do u mean something like

```
 for($i=1; $i<$qcount+1; $i++)
 {                
    $array1[$i];
    $array2[$i+3] ;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Troida but not exactly what i want to implement

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you could slice the first three elements off of `$array1`, if you don't want them.

```
$arraySliced = array_slice($array1, 3);
```

Then just check with this as you would normally:

```
$correct_array = array_intersect_assoc($arraySliced, $array2);
```